# Is it possible to have Parameter validation before executing the Gitlab pipeline manually?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using the Gitlab pipeline for automation testing.  I have a list of parameters (variables) through which we take the input for the test automation pipeline. The problem is that if a user provides a wrong value to any parameter, the job would be executed and would be failed after around 5 minutes.

Is it possible to have Parameter validation before executing the Gitlab pipeline manually?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add an extra job which validates your variables and manually fail the pipeline if they are different than expected.

```
stages:
- validate
- test

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - if [[ "$FOO" != "BAR" ]]; then exit 1; fi

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "run tests"
```